# SSIS Package potential loss of data only in catalog

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I have a package and in the Data Flow the Source Task selects data and one of the columns is `ProcessingTime` and is of type `datetime2(7)`. After some checks and derived columns there is a Slowly Changing Dimension task. Which branch into 'Insert Destination' and 'Update Destination'

[image: SlowlyChangingDimension]

Now the problem is that when i run the package from a sql job I get flowing error:

```
Description = SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Insert Destination" (11) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "OLE DB Destination Input" (24). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.  
Description = SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Insert Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC0209077 occurred, and the error row disposition on "Insert Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.  
Description = There was an error with Insert Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input].Columns[ProcessingTime] on Insert Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]. The column status returned was: "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".  
Description = SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E21.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server"  Hresult: 0x80040E21  Description: "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.".
```

And the **bigger problem** is this error does not occur in any Visual Studio or using 'Run Package...' in the catalog, only from the job.
I checked the type of the Source as the Insert Destination and both has the type `DT_DBTIMESTAMP2` with scale 7.
[image: DBTIMESTAMP2]

I configured a custom 'If not exists then insert else update'-task but I'd like the native SCD task. Any suggestions? Version of SSIS is 13 (2016 version).

Comment: In my opinion (and many others), the slowly changing dimension component should never have been released as it his a host of problems. I would encourage you to find other means to manage your SCD's

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Alright then, thanks :)